# Qt 4.8 Link error with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010

I am receiving a link error when trying to compile my "hello world" Qt program.

`Error  1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: virtual void __thiscall QObject::disconnectNotify(char const *)" (__imp_?disconnectNotify@QObject@@MAEXPBD@Z)   C:\Users\Matthew\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FBIDecryptor\FBIDecryptor\main.obj   FBIDecryptor`

I believe I am missing a library input, but I don't know which library.

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello Qt");
    label->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can you add your project file (.pro for qmake project) to the question.

Comment: Just currious, but why are you using a 7 year old IDE/compiler? Why not use VS2015update3 in this day and age?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am trying to build a quick and simple GUI for windows. Do you have a better idea? I don't know MFC and it cannot use the .net framework, so I need a native GUI app

Comment: @hyde Where is the .pro file? What is qmake?

Comment: For quick start, just go [here](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) and download *Qt 5.7.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 5.3.0, 1.1 GB)* or whatever is the latest MinGW version at the time. If I'm not mistaken, it will include Qt Creator as IDE, and also that version of MinGW toolchain. After installing, just launch Qt Creator and start exploring.

Comment: In general, Online Installer is a better option, as it'll handle upgrades etc, but it can be a bit overwhelming, there are a lot of checkboxes to choose from... If you go with online installer, just install the latest Qt for MinGw, and then also add *matching version* of MinGW to be installed (under Tools or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing reference to QtCore, QtWidget and other Core library modules. Adding the Qt4.8/bin path to the environment variable should fix this.

Found a useful set up guide [here](http://portfolio.delinkx.com/files/Qt.pdf)

Comment: Will this mean I need Qt installed on the target machine or will everything link together in one executable? 

I ask because my destination machine won't have qt installed.

Comment: You need to release (deploy) your application so that it is packaged with QtLibraryFiles (Windows DLL's), these dll's should be installed in the same location as the target executable